# Not able to create custom Predicate while using fast aggregations in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am creating a custom Predicate. It takes an integer and compares it with the value of map.

```
public class LocationPredicate implements Predicate<Key, Portable> {

    private int rssi;

    public LocationPredicate() {
    }

    public LocationPredicate(int rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Entry<Key, Aortable> arg0) {
        return false;
        //int val = arg0.getValue().getData().getLocation().getRssiVal();
        //return (rssi == val ) ;
    }

}
```

When I run the program, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.snmpapp.main.LocationPredicate
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:184)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.MapAggregateWithPredicateMessageTask.getPredicate(MapAggregateWithPredicateMessageTask.java:45)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.call(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:87)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractCallableMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractCallableMessageTask.java:35)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:32)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:172)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:1356)
    at com.snmpapp.main.Main.main(Main.java:370)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aruba.acp.snmpapp.main.LocationPredicate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:149)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:522)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:184)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.MapAggregateWithPredicateMessageTask.getPredicate(MapAggregateWithPredicateMessageTask.java:45)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.map.AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.call(AbstractMapQueryMessageTask.java:87)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractCallableMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractCallableMessageTask.java:35)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

I am little bit confused. Do I need to create the Predicate on the server? I am running as Hcast client and the client is creating the predicate.

As far as I know, when you create the predicate, it is sent as a serialized object to the hazelcast server.

Also, I tried to implement Predicate as Serializable, but it didnt help.
    Thanks

Comment: Clarified supporting text including moving it out of the code example.

Comment: Tidy language in supporting comments

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced with Hazelcast but as far as I know during serialisation and deserialisation you can transfer state (in this case the member variable) but not the behaviour (your actual implementation of apply method). Somehow (I am not experienced with this technology) you should provide your class to the Hazelcast's class loader (maybe copying to the classpath). Good luck!

Comment: That is right, the class needs to be on the Hazelcast node classpath. That said, just deploy the classes. With Hazelcast 3.8 you could also use a lite-member as a class-source (see documentation) but for now I'd recommend to get the class on the classpath.

Comment: That's something new. I will try out class-source. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The class needs to be on the classpath of all nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. I have created a class on server side. All cluster nodes needs to know about the class.